# How to determine the height of an InputBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, inputbox

I'm using the InputBox from the VB .dll. When I display it, I want to put it in a particular place relative to the controls it will have an impact on (out of their way). So I have this pseudocode for showing the InputBox ("selectionStart" is a Point assigned to on MouseDown):

```
int HeightOfInputBox = ? <- What is this value?
int XPos = selectionStart.X;
int YPos = selectionStart.Y - HeightOfInputBox; 
Interaction.InputBox("Prompt", "Title", "DefaultResponse", XPos, YPos);
```

My question is: What is the height of an InputBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have access to the object to get the `Height` or `Width` information. The only properties available are what you set when you initialize it. If you need the `Height` you will need to roll your own. This CodeProject [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10181/InputBox-in-C) is an example on how to, you could just add another intializer to set the Width and Height of the InputBox.

i.e.    `InputBox("Prompt", "Title", "DefaultResponse", XPos, YPos, Width, Height);`

Comment: But surely the InputBox has a defined/default height... It may grow depending on how text you send it, but my Prompt is not very long, so it should be the default height. I guess I can just experiment, and see how it looks.

Comment: @Clay You are right, it probably does just havn't seen it documented anywhere

Comment: Micro$oft should pay some cats (&| chicks) to prowl these "forums" and answer questions like these.

Answer (score -1):

you can use 
Me.ActiveControl
for the current control

Comment: What do you mean? What is "Me"? this? Can you provide a code sample demonstrating what you're suggesting?